# Rfresh the parents component while updating in detailCellRendering in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

***We have One parents componet Template in That i m using one detailsCellRendering componet for cellRedering in ag-grid..in the detailsCellRendering componet I am updating TextValue and after clicking on handleDoneValue event (done button ) the Template page should also refresh.But I am not able to do ...i need help like how can i update Template page while updating in DetailsCellRending Component.***

```
class Template extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Channel Field",
          field: "field",
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
          filterParams: {
            buttons: ["reset"],
            debounceMs: 1000,
            suppressAndOrCondition: true, // it will remove AND/OR conditions
            filterOptions: [
              "contains",
              "notContains",
              "equals",
              "notEqual",
              "startsWith",
              "endsWith"
            ]
          },
          cellRendererParams: {
            prop1: "this is prop1"
        },
          cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
        },
        {
          headerName: "Mapping from Your Data",
          field: "mapping_field",
          filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
        },
          {
            headerName: skuValue,
            field: "value",
          },
        {
          headerName: "Status",
          field: "status",
          filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
          filterParams: {
            values: function (params) {
              // simulating async delay
              setTimeout(function () {
                params.success(["True", "False"]);
              }, 500);
            }
          },
          // cellRenderer: "ColourRender",
          cellStyle: params => {
            if (params.value === "Mapped") {
              //mark mapped cells as green
              return { color: 'green' };
            } else {
              return { color: 'red' };
            }
          }
        },
        {
          headerName: "Required",
          field: "required",
          filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
          cellRenderer: "BooleanRender",
          filterParams: {
            values: function (params) {
              // simulating async delay
              setTimeout(function () {
                params.success(["True", "False"]);
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      columnDefsforSku: [

        {
          headerName: "Channel Field",
          field: "field",
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
          filterParams: {
            buttons: ["reset"],
            debounceMs: 1000,
            suppressAndOrCondition: true, // it will remove AND/OR conditions
            filterOptions: [
              "contains",
              "notContains",
              "equals",
              "notEqual",
              "startsWith",
              "endsWith",
              // "In List",
              // "Not In List"
            ]
          },
          cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
        },

        {
          headerName: "Mapping from Your Data",
          field: "mapping_field",
          filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
        },
        {
          headerName: "Status",
          field: "status",
          filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
          filterParams: {
            values: function (params) {
              // simulating async delay
              setTimeout(function () {
                params.success(["True", "False"]);
              }, 500);
            }
          },
          cellStyle: params => {
            if (params.value === "Mapped") {
              //mark mapped cells as green
              return { color: 'green' };
            } else {
              return { color: 'red' };
            }
          }
        },
        {
          headerName: "Required",
          field: "required",
          filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
          cellRenderer: "BooleanRender",
          filterParams: {
            values: function (params) {
              // simulating async delay
              setTimeout(function () {
                params.success(["True", "False"]);
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      components: {
        DetailCellRenderer: {DetailCellRenderer},
      },
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        resizable: true,
        // tooltipComponent: "customTooltip",
        floatingFilter: true,
        minWidth: 170,
        sortable: true,
      },
      rowModelType: "serverSide",
      frameworkComponents: {
        customNoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
        loadingRender: loadingRender,
        myDetailCellRenderer: DetailCellRenderer,
        customTooltip: CustomTooltip,
        BooleanRender: BooleanRender,

        // ColourRender: ColourRender,
      },
      context: { componentParent: this },
      pagination: true,
      serverSideStoreType: "full",
      rowSelection: "multiple",
      loadingCellRenderer: "loadingRender",
      loadingCellRendererParams: { loadingMessage: "One moment please..." },
      loadingOverlayComponent: "loadingRender",
      totalProductsCount: 0,
      catalogfilterCount: 0,
      noRowsOverlayComponent: "customNoRowsOverlay",
      noRowsOverlayComponentParams: {
        noRowsMessageFunc: function () {
          return "Please Select Product Preview"
        }
      },
      getDetailRowData: function (params) {
        // params.successCallback([]);
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
      },
      sideBar: 'filters',
      tooltipShowDelay: 0,
      paginationPageSize: 100,
      cacheBlockSize: 30,
      filterStatus: false,
      sweetAlert: "",
      allSKu: [],
      sku: localStorage.getItem("skuPreviewProduct"),
      isProductPrevewSelected: false,
      skuInputValue: "",
      loading: false,
      product_id: localStorage.getItem("products_ids") ? localStorage.getItem("products_ids") : null,
      // loadingForDetails:  localStorage.getItem("loadings")
    };
 <Grid item xs={10}>
              <div
                id="myGrid"
                style={{
                  height: "90%",
                  width: "90%",
                }}
                className="ag-theme-alpine template"
              >
                <AgGridReact
                  columnDefs={this.state.product_id ?  columnDefs : columnDefsforSku}
                  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                  rowModelType={rowModelType}
                  masterDetail={true}
                  enableCellChangeFlash={true}
                  masterDetail={true}
                  detailCellRenderer={'myDetailCellRenderer'}
                  detailRowHeight={350}
                  height={400}
                  width={600}
                  animateRows={true}
                  frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
                  embedFullWidthRows={true}
                  loadingOverlayComponent={loadingOverlayComponent}
                  loadingCellRenderer={loadingCellRenderer} // default loading renderer
                  loadingCellRendererParams={loadingCellRendererParams} // renderer Params to load msg
                  noRowsOverlayComponent={noRowsOverlayComponent} // default no rows overlay component
                  noRowsOverlayComponentParams={noRowsOverlayComponentParams} // to show default no rows message
                  paginationPageSize={this.state.paginationPageSize} // pagination page size
                  onColumnVisible={this.onColumnVisible.bind(this)}
                  getDetailRowData={getDetailRowData}
                  cacheBlockSize={cacheBlockSize}
                  detailCellRendererParams={detailCellRendererParams }
                />
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
)

 1. **List item**

}



// DetailsCellRendering page



import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TemplateTab from "../views/FunctionalComponents/TemplateTab"
import { TEMPLATE_MARKETPLACE_FEILD_MAPPING, TEMPLATE_API } from "../configurations/configApi";
import { apiEdit, fetchUrl } from "../apiActions/action";
import LoadingOverlay from "../components/overlays/LoadingOverlay";
import Templates from 'views/Tables/Templates';
// import Template from 'views/Tables/Templates';


const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 20,

  }
}));


const DetailCellRenderer = ({ data, params, api, node}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const marketplaceId = localStorage.getItem("marketplaceId") ? localStorage.getItem("marketplaceId") : ""  ;
  const skuValue = localStorage.getItem("skuPreviewProduct") ? localStorage.getItem("skuPreviewProduct") : "";

  const fetchAllTemplate = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    var soniServe = `${TEMPLATE_API}${marketplaceId}/?sku=${skuValue}&filter=${"[]"}`;
    fetchUrl(soniServe, ({ status, response }) => {
      if (status) {
        let refreshValue = response.data.response[0].mappings.filter(item => data.id === item.id);
        localStorage.setItem("cellRenderId", refreshValue && refreshValue[0]&& refreshValue[0].id )
        setAllData(refreshValue && refreshValue[0])
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        if (response.response &&
          response.response.status &&
          ((response.response.status === 401))
        ) {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          localStorage.removeItem("email");
          window.location = "/auth/login-page";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllData(data)
  }, data)


// update text value
  const handleDoneValue = (textValue) => {
    const productId = allData && allData.id;
    let value = textValue
    // updating the existing labels
    const urlForSave = `${TEMPLATE_MARKETPLACE_FEILD_MAPPING}${productId}/`;
    const methodOfSave = "put";
    const data = { "mappings": { "text_value": value } }
    apiEdit(urlForSave, data, methodOfSave, ({ status, response }) => {
      if (status) {
        // window.location = `/configuration/details/${marketplaceId}`
        fetchAllTemplate();
        // inputMethod === "saveAs" && this.fetchProductDisplay("saveAs");
      } else {
        if (response.response &&
          response.response.status &&
          ((response.response.status === 401))

        ) {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          localStorage.removeItem("email");
          window.location = "/auth/login-page";
        } else if (
          (response &&
            response.status &&
            (response.status === 404 ||
              response.status === 500)) ||
          !response
        ) {
          window.location = "/error";
        } else {
          // to show some popups
          window.location = "/error";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container style={{ paddingTop: "10px" }}>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            {allData && allData.field ? allData.field : null}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            { allData && allData.mapping_field ? allData.mapping_field : null}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3}> 
          {urlCheck && urlCheck[0] === "https" ||  urlCheck && urlCheck[0] === "http"? <a href={allData && allData.value} target="_blank">{allData && allData.value}</a>  : allData && allData.value ? allData.value : null}
            {/* { data && data.value ? data.value : null} */}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3} >
            {allData && allData.status}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={4} justify="flex-end" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            Description
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8} >
            <Paper className="templateBox">
              <span style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>What value should we send for each product's "{data.field}"? </span>
              <TemplateTab allCellData={data} handleDoneValue={handleDoneValue}
                 />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <LoadingOverlay showOverlay={loading} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default DetailCellRenderer;

Comment: pass one state flag from parent to child and when you update the child set the state of the parent so it will also rerender

Comment: In ag-grid we can not pass the props in cellRendering component. But can you please give me hint.